# Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat) - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory

Attempting to clone part of an image causes the OutOfMemoryException to be thrown.

The line that causes the error is:

```
TileImage = TileFileImage.Clone(CloneRect, TileFileImage.PixelFormat);
```

`TileFileImage` is 271x271px in size.

`CloneRect`'s upper left corner is at (186, 16) and its lower right corner is at (202, 32) before the exception is thrown.

Both `TileImage` and `TileFileImage` are `Bitmap`s.

`CloneRect` can never be larger than 271x271px.

Logic in the method the above statement is in prevents the rectangle from exceeding the bounds of the image.

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I checked over my logic and found the problem.

Some indices could end up outside the source `Bitmap`.